# C# cast generic T in abstract class<T> to dynamic

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

This is what I want to do in C# (within `class Helper` - without generic arguments),

```
List<AbstractClass<dynamic>> data;

public void Add<T>(AbstractClass<T> thing)
{
    this.data.Add((AbstractClass<dynamic>) thing);
}
```

This helper class would take and work with `AbstractClass<>` objects and give back `AbstractClass<>` of specific generic type. `AbstractClass<T>` contains many functions which return `T` / take in `T` like `public T Invoke()`.
For Helper class `T` cannot be known beforehand. The `Add<T>(.. thing)` function is not in a class of type `T`.
To be used like this in Helper class's functions,

```
foreach(var c in data.Where(x => ...))
{
    // public T Invoke() { ... } function within AbstractClass<T>
    var b = c.Invoke(); 
    // logic
}
```

This also fails,

```
List<AbstractClass<object>> data;

public void Add<T>(AbstractClass<T> thing)
{
    this.data.Add((AbstractClass<object>) thing);
}
```

Now I think I can have,

```
List<dynamic> data; // or List<object> data;

public void Add<T>(AbstractClass<T> thing)
{
    this.data.Add(thing);
}
```

but I want the constraint that List named data has only elements of type like

```
ConcreteClass : AbstractClass<OtherClass>
```

So we would know that there is an `public T Invoke()` function but we do not know what it returns. This is helpful to avoid mistakes of say misspelling Invocke and only knowing at run-time.

I want to avoid casting to `dynamic` every time to invoke functions that give back generic type T

Comment: Why not declare data as `List<AbstractClass<T>> data;`?

Comment: The class which contains the `List<..> data` is not of type T. The `Add<T>(... thing)` function must handle adding many different concrete objects which extend the AbstractClass while not knowing what T is. I hope that makes some sense. That is `class Helper { ... List<..> data; public void Add<T>(... data) { ... } .. }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want to do you are going to need to use a [Contravariant interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var m = new Helper();
        m.Add(new ConcreteClass());

        m.Process();
    }

    class Helper
    {
        List<IAbstractClass<OtherClassBase>> data = new List<IAbstractClass<OtherClassBase>>();

        public void Add(IAbstractClass<OtherClassBase> thing)
        {
            this.data.Add(thing);
        }

        public void Process()
        {
            foreach(var c in data.Where(x => x.ShouldBeProcessed()))
            {
                var b = c.Invoke();
                Console.WriteLine(b.Question);
                var castData = b as OtherClass;
                if (castData != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(castData.Answer);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IAbstractClass<out T>
    {
        bool ShouldBeProcessed();
        T Invoke();
    }

    abstract class AbstractClass<T> : IAbstractClass<T>
    {
        public bool ShouldBeProcessed()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public abstract T Invoke();
    }

    class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass<OtherClass>
    {
        public override OtherClass Invoke()
        {
            return new OtherClass();
        }
    }


    class OtherClassBase
    {
        public string Question { get { return "What is the answer to life, universe, and everything?"; } }
    }

    class OtherClass : OtherClassBase
    {
        public int Answer { get { return 42; } }
    }
}
```

You do not need to tell `Add` what kind of class you are passing it, all that matters is it derives from the type specified. You could do `public void Add(IAbstractClass<object> thing)` and every class would work, but `Invoke()` would only return objects inside the foreach loop.

You need to figure out what is the most derived class you want `Invoke()` to return and that is what you set as the type in the list.

Comment: Except a single instance Helper needs to be able to take in classes which extend `AbstractClass<A>, AbtrasctClass<B>, ... AbtrasctClass<Z>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var m1 = new Helper<OtherClass>();
        m1.Add(new ConcreteClass());
        var m2 = new Helper<int>();
        m2.Add(new ConcreteClass2());
    }
    class Helper<T>
    {
        List<AbstractClass<T>> data = new List<AbstractClass<T>>();

        public void Add<T1>(T1 thing) where T1 : AbstractClass<T>
        {
            this.data.Add(thing);
        }
    }
    class AbstractClass<T> { }
    class OtherClass { }
    class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass<OtherClass> { }
    class ConcreteClass2 : AbstractClass<int> { }
}
```